# JavaScript: class propery is undefined when called from a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, scope

I want to store all ids of anchors (contained in a webpage) into an array of `Link` objects. I am not a JS programmer so maybe I am missing some fundamental knowledge but googling and trying to implement solutions that worked for others did not help me (Like binding the contest, the fat arrow and so on). 
What I have understand is that my `this` object is in the wrong scope, it contains the full path of the clicked link (the `href`) but just three lines above I used this ad it worked as expected in:  `$.each(this.inner_aol, function(index, element){ ... }`

Here is the JS code:

```
// Link object
class Link{
    anchor = null;

    constructor(anchor){
        this.anchor = anchor;
    }

    getHref(){
        return $(this).attr("href");
    }

    myToString(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

// Object containing an array of Links and some methods to manage them
class ArrayOfLinks{

    constructor(selector){
        this.selector = selector;
        this.anchorOnClick = this.anchorOnClick.bind(this);
    }

    fillArrWithLinks(){
        var tmp_aol = new Array();  
        $(this.selector).each(function(){
            console.log("Pushing " + $(this).attr("href"));
            tmp_aol.push($(this));      
        });

        this.inner_aol = tmp_aol;
        //this.selector = selector;
        //return tmp_aol;
    }

    myToString(){
        console.log("Inner AOLs " + this.inner_aol.toString());
    }

    printAllElements(){
        $.each(this.inner_aol, function(index, element){
            console.log("printAllElements -> " + $(element).attr("href"));
        });
    }

    anchorOnClick(){
        $.each(this.inner_aol, function(index, element){
            $(element).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

/* *****************************
************************************************************************
the problem is in the following line when using this*/
                console.log("Link to div: " + $(element).attr("href") + " position into inner_aol: " + $.inArray($(element).attr("href"), this.inner_aol) + " my this is: " +this);
            });
        })
    }

    isAllowed(clicked_element){
        if(($(clicked_element).hasClass("deactive")) && (true)){
            console.log("this step is allowed");
        }
    }

}


l = new Link("test");
aol = new ArrayOfLinks(".link");
aol.fillArrWithLinks();
aol.myToString();
aol.printAllElements();
aol.anchorOnClick();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your click callbacks to your class reference, like this:

```
anchorOnClick(){
    var thisRef = this;
    $.each(this.inner_aol, function(index, element){
        $(element).click((function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            /* *****************************
            ************************************************************************/
            console.log("Link to div: " + $(element).attr("href") + " position into inner_aol: " + $.inArray($(element).attr("href"), this.inner_aol) + " my this is: " +this);
        }).bind(thisRef));
    })
}
```